# Are valueChangeListeners required for amx:selectBooleanCheckbox?

Tags: java, jdeveloper, valuechangelistener, oracle-adf-mobile

I am using jDeveloper 12.1.3 and MAF 2.0.0.0. I'm attempting to build a settings page in a mobile application. All the items are based on the local SQLite database on the mobile device. I have the POJO (getters and setters) and DC classes set up, the initializedb.sql and connectionfactory.java files ready. Here's my problem:

Any time I check one of the checkboxes, the page refreshes and wipes out everything on the page. I don't have any valueChangeListener associated with any of the checkboxes.

I'm very very new to ADF and MAF, so I assume that I'm missing something simple. Thanks in advance for questions/comments/concerns.

Here's the associated code:

XML for the item itself:

`<amx:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bindings.requireTagAndStateOrVin.inputValue}"
                               label="#{bindings.requireTagAndStateOrVin.label}" id="sbc1"/>`

Java from the Settings class:
    `public void setRequireTagAndStateOrVin(String requireTagAndStateOrVin) {
        this.requireTagAndStateOrVin = requireTagAndStateOrVin;
    }

```
public String getRequireTagAndStateOrVin() {
    return requireTagAndStateOrVin;
}`
```

Java from the SettingsDC class

`public class SettingsDC {
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

```
public SettingsDC() {
    super();
}

public Settings[] getSettings(){
    Settings[] settings = null;
    settings = getSettingsFromDB();
    return settings;
}

private Settings[] getSettingsFromDB(){
    Connection conn = null;
    List returnValue = new ArrayList();
    try {
        conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;");
        while (result.next()){
           settings.setRequireTagAndStateOrVin(result.getString("REQUIRE_TAG_AND_STATE_OR_VIN_IND"));
           returnValue.add(settings);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Utility.ApplicationLogger.severe(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    Collections.sort(returnValue);
    return (Settings[]) returnValue.toArray(new Settings[returnValue.size()]);
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l)
{
  propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l)
{
  propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

You are dOing your settings page in a hard way.

Please use the prefrences that already embded in maf

37 (Core). Setting Device Preferences: 
http://youtu.be/C469lObO_TQ

Comment: These are settings for the application itself, not for the mobile device. Things like start character, start number, etc

Comment: I still don't see a reason not to do it with MAF embed preferences, to make it clear, the prefrences in MAF is the application prefrences not device, and you should do it that way so the user feel the same experience in both iOS and Android.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This works very well! The issue now becomes being able to set these preferences after a custom log in. If we were using the embedded MAF login, this would be no problem.

Comment: You can set/get the preferences pro-grammatically check this doc http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/m09-user-preferences-1944994.pdf